# Filter result from firebase ObservableCollection

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to filter records from FirebaseDB in my Xamarin app.

Following code returns all records from DB:

```
internal ObservableCollection<MessageModel> GetMessages(Guid messageId)
{
 var result = (firebase).Child("Messages").AsObservable<MessageModel>().AsObservableCollection();

 return result;
}
```

But when I apply Where it returns 0 records event that se that I have records in DB that match MessageId

```
internal ObservableCollection<MessageModel> GetMessages(Guid messageId)
    {
        var result = (firebase).Child("Messages").AsObservable<MessageModel>().AsObservableCollection().Where(s => s.Id == messageId); ;

        return new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>(result);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: anything update?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use the following code to query data from firebase.

```
 public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
          {
              Name = item.Object.Name,
              PersonId = item.Object.PersonId
          }).ToList();
    }

  public async Task<Person> GetPerson(int personId)
    {
        var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>();
        return allPersons.Where(a => a.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();
    }

 public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Eldlabs Anything update? Please give some feedback for my reply.